# Serial COM port data over WebRTC

Tags: serial-port, webrtc

I'm currently looking at options to allow me to build a remote COM-port solution.
The idea is to be able to access from my remote PC, another PC that's directly connected to a device locally via its serial COM-port.

I know that the obivous answer is to use a VPN between the 2 Internet connected PCs.
However, I need this solution to be as seamless to the end-user as possible.
i.e. no installing and configuring VPN software, etc.

So I was thinking that WebRTC would be great because the end-user can simply use their web-browser and not have to install any additional software.

My question is, is it possible to stream the COM port data between the 2 PCs via WebRTC?
If so, can you please point me in the right direction as to how I can go about achieving this?

Sorry if this is a ridiculous question, I'm very new to WebRTC, just exploring my options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work great!

Networking wise you get NAT Traversal. That means the two computers can be in completely different networks, and still communicate. You may have to run a TURN server if P2P isn't possible.

Data wise you can exchange anything you want via data channels. It is datagram based and you can send/receive binary data. You get a callback telling you how much has been delivered, that way you can detect backpressure.

Are you ok with installing software on the remote host? You can do something like Pion WebRTC's [data-channels](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/data-channels). This shows you can have a browser connect to a Go process via WebRTC. Then use [tarm/serial](https://github.com/tarm/serial) on the remote host to interact with the device.

If you want a browser on both ends there is the [Web Serial API](https://wicg.github.io/serial/) I haven't used it myself though. That locks you into only doing Chromium which might be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'll look into those suggestions. One thing that I should have mentioned is the fact that on my remote side I'm forced to use a proprietary desktop application that talks to the device connected to the PC on the local end. So I would need to 'route' traffic from this desktop app to the webRTC app. I believe I can achieve this using com0com virtual com port redirection. Also, yes I'm ok with installing software on my remote end.

Comment: Awesome! I feel like that all should work. The only thing I am unsure about is com0com never done anything like that.